# Cannot import zmq in python using pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying to use the `zmq` Python library but it is not recognized and I have already installed it by using the following command:

```
pip3 install pyzmq
```

I am using `PyCharm` IDE.

The run output gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Operações/Desktop/Testes/teste.py", line 2, in <module>
    import zmq
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zmq'
```

Does anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Try to checking pyzmq --version and make sure install pyzmq draft support : https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/draft.html

Comment: It is not there, do i have to install inside or something?

Comment: Are you sure your script is run by `Python3`? Because you have installed the `zmq` lib with `pip3` so you should use `Python3`.

Comment: sure, version 3.8.0

Comment: Check the installation: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq

Comment: Under File > Settings > Project: "your project" > Project interpreter, check which interpreter you are using and check if the package is installed.

Comment: @SimonFink oh, its not there, what should i do?

Comment: Install it for the interpreter in use or change to the interpreter for which you installed pyzmq already.

Comment: @SimonFink i dont know if im doing it right but keeps failing

Comment: I copy and pasted the zmq library from the python38 folder to the project venv, will it cause any problem?

Comment: You should check, how to install packages for virtual environments. Alternatively you can try to let PyCharm install that packages for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pip, try installing pyzmq from File/Settings in PyCharm.

> 1. Open the `Settings/Preferences`
> 2. Navigate to `Project: -> Python Interpreter`
> 3. Klick the `+` at the bottom of the list
> 4. Search for your package of choice and hit `Install Package`

For more details on installing/uninstalling packages in PyCharm:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html